# Why not always configure for max number of event hub partitions?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

The [Azure Event Hubs overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-overview/) article states the following:

> The number of partitions is specified at the Event Hub creation time
>   and must be between 8 and 32. Partitions are a data organization
>   mechanism and are more related to the degree of downstream parallelism
>   required in consuming applications than to Event Hubs throughput. This
>   makes the choice of the number of partitions in an Event Hub directly
>   related to the number of concurrent readers you expect to have. After
>   Event Hub creation, the partition count is not changeable; you should
>   consider this number in terms of long-term expected scale. You can
>   increase the 32 partition limit by contacting the Azure Service Bus
>   team.

Since you cannot change the number of partitions on your event hub after initial creation, why not just always configure it to the maximum number of partitions, 32? I do not see any [pricing](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/event-hubs/) implications in doing this. Is there some performance trade off?

Also, as another side note, I appear to be able to create an event hub with less than 8 partitions. The article says it must be between 8-32. Not sure why it says that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its my understanding that each partition requires its own consumer. You could do this via multi-threading on a single process, multiple processes, or even via multipage machines each running a process. But this comes with a degree of complexity. Either the management of all the processes to ensure that all partitions are being consumed, or for synchronizing items/events that span partitions.

So the implicates are less about pricing then they are about scalability/complexity. :)

Comment: I figured it was something along these lines, however, the "Scale out Event Processing with Event Hubs" C# sample seems to make this pretty simple through the use of `EventProcessorHost`, `EventProcessor`, and `EventProcessorFactory`. See https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Service-Bus-Event-Hub-45f43fc3 or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2015/02/24/scaling-azure-event-hubs-processing-with-worker-roles.aspx

Comment: It automates things for certain. But there's also some trade-offs. Such as having multiple consumer processes or having more discrete control over the replay of events.